# Can I filter foreign keys in Django admin_

Tags: django, django-admin

The Django admin interface allows to give defaults by using links like `/admin/blog_app/post_model/add/?blog_id=1`, so it is easy to create links for adding objects with pre-populated fields.

I wonder if there is also a way to give filters for foreign fields. In the example link, I generate a link that can be used to pre-select a blog when creating a `Post` object by giving its ID. Now I would like to give another parameter to filter, e.g., the author field, like this: `/admin/blog_app/post_model/add/?blog_id=1&author_filter=author__blog_id=1` such that the author dropdown only contains authors for the corresponding blog.

Models for the example above:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog) # Possibly even a ManyToMany Field
    # Other fields like name, email, etc.

class Post(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog) # preselected by URL parameter
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author) # field that should be filtered in admin, e.g., by author__blog_id
    # Other fields like content, category, tags, etc.
```